# How do i store an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Im writing a function that returns an array of two arrays that i need:

```
e.g.
arrayX = zeros(1, k);
arrayY = zeros(1, k);

for (i=1:k)
xk=x>i;
dec_nums = histc(bin2dec(num2str([xk(:) y(:)],'%1d')),0:3);
things = reshape(flipud(dec_nums),2,[])';

sensitivity = things(1) / (things(1) + things(3));
specificity = things(4) / (things(4) + things(2));
s1 = 1 - sensitivity
s2 = 1 - specificity
arrayX(i, :) = s1;
arrayY(i, :) = s2;

array = [arrayX, arrayY];
```

but when i call array(1), it returns only the first number, nothing more?

-edit-
changing it to array = [arrayX; arrayY] returns

```
array =

    0.1061    0.1061    0.1061
    0.1259    0.1259    0.1259
    0.1324    0.1324    0.1324
    0.9999    0.9999    0.9999
    0.9997    0.9997    0.9997
    0.9996    0.9996    0.9996
```

which doesnt seem right either....is there anyway to simply return two arrays, so that when the function is done i'm able to get arrayX and arrayY?

Answer (score 2):

Right I figured the answer! To return a function with two values, you'd have to specify [x y] on the function and then call it using

[x y] = COMPARE(something, somethingelse);

this stores two values

```
function [arrayX arrayY] = COMPARE( x, y )
%COMPARE Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

k=3;
arrayX = zeros(1, k);
arrayY = zeros(1, k);

for (i=1:k)
    xk=x>i;
    dec_nums = histc(bin2dec(num2str([xk(:) y(:)],'%1d')),0:3);
    things = reshape(flipud(dec_nums),2,[])';

    sensitivity = things(1) / (things(1) + things(3));
    specificity = things(4) / (things(4) + things(2));
    s1 = 1 - sensitivity
    s2 = 1 - specificity
    arrayX(:, i) = s1;
    arrayY(:, i) = s2;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array` variable has dimension `1 x 2k`, so the first element is actually the first element of `arrayX`.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
array = [arrayX ; arrayY];
```

This array has dimension `2 x k`.
You can index it as:

```
array(:,i)
```

to get the `i`-th pair of numbers as a 2 dimensional column vector.